# GetElementById in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

What is the equivalent of `document.getElementByName` AngularJS ?
I'm doing the edit portion of the form using AngularJS, and wanted to inject the values ​​obtained od database within an input . After that would edit the input content and subsequently perform  `ALTER TABLE`.
The backend is in PHP.

**EDit**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myCrud">
<head>
    <title>CRUD AngularJS</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular/angular.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.css">
<style>
    .jumbotron {

        text-align: center;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    .table {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .form-control {
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module("myCrud", []);
    angular.module("myCrud").controller("myCrudCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.tit = "CRUD AngularJS e PHP";

        $scope.adicionarUsuario = function (usuario) {
            $http.post("salvar.php", usuario).success(function (data){
                delete $scope.usuario;
                $scope.usuarioForm.$setPristine();
                carregarUsuario();
            });
        };
        var carregarUsuario = function () {
            $http.get("buscar.php").then(function (retorno){
                console.log(retorno.data);
                $scope.usuarios = retorno.data;
            }); 
        };

        $scope.editarUsuario = function (usuario){
            $scope.messagem =  usuario.nome;

          /*  $http.post("editar.php", usuario).success(function (data){
                delete $scope.usuario;
                $scope.usuarioForm.$setPristine();
                carregarUsuario();                
            });   */
            //////////////////////////////////THE QUESTION POINT


        };        
        $scope.apagarUsuario = function (usuario) {               
            $http.delete("apagar.php", {params: {id: usuario}}).success(function (data, status){
                carregarUsuario();
                $scope.messagem(data.msg);
            });
        };
        $scope.ordenarPor = function (campo) {
                $scope.criterioDeOrdenacao = campo;
                $scope.direcaoDaOrdenacao = !$scope.direcaoDaOrdenacao;
            };

        carregarUsuario();

    });
</script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myCrudCtrl">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h4>{{tit}}</h4>
        <h6>{{messagem}}</h6>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="criterioDeBusca" placeholder="O que você está buscando?"/>
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <td><a href="" ng-click="ordenarPor('nome')"><b>Nome</b></a></td>
                <td><a href="" ng-click="ordenarPor('email')"><b>Email</b></a></td>
                <td><b>Password</b></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="usuario in usuarios | filter:criterioDeBusca | orderBy:criterioDeOrdenacao:direcaoDaOrdenacao">
                <td>{{usuario.nome}}</td><!-- <a href="#" editable-text="usuario.name">{{ usuario.name || "empty" }}</a>-->
                <td>{{usuario.email}}</td>
                <td>{{usuario.pass}}</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-xs btn-alert" ng-click="editarUsuario(usuario)">Editar</button></td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" ng-click="apagarUsuario(usuario.id)">Apagar</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <hr>

        <form name="usuarioForm">
            <input class="form-control" id="inputnome" type="text" ng-model="usuario.nome" placeholder="Nome">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="usuario.email" placeholder="Email">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="usuario.pass" placeholder="Senha">
        </form>

        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="adicionarUsuario(usuario)">Adicionar</button>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean? Angular doesn't stop you from using `document.getElementsByName`/`document.getElementById`.

Comment: In what context are you trying to `getElementByName`? I feel that you are probably trying to do something that `ng-model` facilitates.

Comment: Just use data binding. Trying to force stuff into controls with jquery leads to ugly, unmaintainable code. If you want that type of code, angular may not be your best choice.

Comment: I will edit the question with my code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amy Blankenship hit the nail on the head there, that you should use Angular's strongest features (like data binding) instead of getting elements directly.

That said, if you really want to do this, you can:

`angular.element( document.getElementById('someElement') )`